# PostgreSQL multiple join

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, group-by

I would like to make multiple joins in one query, I have four tables for that with the following structure:

> Table 1 fields, t1: *did (int), finished (datetime), userid (int)*
>
> Table 2 fields, t2: *userid (int), name*
>
> Table 3 fields, t3: *blid (int), did (int), count (int), btid(int)*
>
> Table 4 fields, t4: *btid(int), denom (int)*

I want to make a query where I would get all fields of `t1` except for that one joined with `t2` in that case I would like to show `t2.name` when `t1.userid = t2.userid` This is fair simple:

```
select t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid from t1 inner join on t1.userid=t2.userid
```

But I also want to add a column composed by the following query:

```
select sum(t3.count*t4.denom) from t3 inner join t4 on t3.btid=t4.btid
```

Only when `t3.did=t1.did` I don't know if it would be an outer join or otherwise, but I want to add the previous query as a column in the first query and it would be something like:

> t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid, "total"?

The real-world problem is that users make money deposits `t1` users information are held in `t2`. The amount deposited is described in `t3` for every deposit `t1.did` and related denominations of each deposit breakdown, in `t3` are described in `t4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this easiest as a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid,
       (select sum(t3.count * t4.denom)
        from t3 inner join
             t4
             on t3.btid = t4.btid
        where t3.did = t1.did
      ) as value
from t1 inner join  t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

For this version, you want indexes on `t3(did, btid, count)` and `t4(btid, denom)`.

You can also phrase this as a `join` and `group by`:

```
select t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid,
       sum(t3.count * t4.denom)
from t1 inner join  t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid left join
     t3
     on t3.did = t1.did left join
     t4
     on t3.btid = t4.btid
group by t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid;
```

Comment: When writing a scalar subquery like one in the first snippet, one should keep in mind that in PostgreSQL  it is executed *for each row* returned by the SELECT clause. That is, for each row from t1 join t2 in this case it will do inner join of t3 and t4.

On the contrary, the second version will scan every table just once. The difference is negligible when there are 1000 rows in every table, while for 100k rows in every table the first is ~3x slower on my machine.

Comment: @Dmitry . . . Is that with the recommended indexes (which I just added to the answer)?

Comment: Yes. On tables with 100k rows GROUP BY takes ~350 ms (indexes do not matter). Scalar subquery with your indexes takes ~700ms, without indexes -- I cancelled execution after it had spent 30 seconds.
My first attempt (3x difference) was with indexes on all columns involved into joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` clause:

```
select t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid, sum(t3.count*t4.denom)
from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.userid=t2.userid
inner join t3 on t1.did = t3.did
inner join t4 on t3.btid = t4.btid
group by t1.did, t1.finished, t2.name, t2.userid
```